# How to upgrade from .Net Version 2 to version 4 on Windows 7

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, windows-7

I am trying to upgrade from Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5485; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5491 to Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.36373. So that I can use Asp.net V4 on my local IIS server.

When I go into Control Panel > System and Security > Administrative Tools > Internet Information Services and select Change ,NET Framework Version the drop down box displays Version:2.0.50727 . I can select Version:4.0.30319 and select OK but this does not appear to have any effect i.e When I exit and go back in to the control panel it has reverted back to Version 2 in the display.

Comment: Pasting a screen shot can show what's up. Also you showed no experience on application pool concept. Without knowing that you won't easily find the answer. Find an IIS book and spend some time.

Comment: Screen shot http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img922/8008/PltrNG.png

Answer (score -1):

As you showed in the screen shot, you configured the wrong place.

The actual setting you should change is the .NET Framework (CLR) version of an application pool. Read carefully any IIS book or online documentation, and you should soon learn what I mean.

Comment: Thanks again I just changed the intranet application pool to use version 4 and it worked fine. More importantly it allowed me to use the asp features in V4 that caused an error in V2

Comment: Really? The answer you provide is `Read carefully any IIS book or online documentation`?

Comment: @nathansizemore I was thanked because I said "The actual setting you should change is the .NET Framework (CLR) version of an application pool. ". You shouldn't expect a useful answer to be lengthy, as long as it hits the point.